# draw a tree diagram to determine the probability that for 2 days in a row he will be late

Tags: probability

the chance that Charles is late for class is 2/5.
-What is the possibility that Charles is not late for class?
the possibility that Charles is not late for class is 3/5.
-Draw a tree diagram to determine the probability that for two days in a row Charles will be late: both days, one of the days only.
Is this correct?[image]

Comment: If his lateness on the second day is independent of his lateness on the first day, what is the probability he would be late on the second day?

Comment: The tree is correct ... now you need to assign probabilities to each branch ...